# UK expat living and working in Spain - switching to freelancing possible?

Tags: eu-citizens, spain, freelance

I'm an English expat and have been living and working in Mallorca, Spain for the past two years.

I have been contacted by a remote-only software development company who have employees globally, and their HQ is in Australia.

If I were to take a job with this company, what would I need to do to continue living and working here in Mallorca? Would I need to register my own business, pay an accountant to sort out things? I've never worked 'freelance' before, if this would even count as freelancing.

Also, with Brexit potentially on the horizon, could switching from working with a Spanish company to a non-Spanish one potentially jeapordize my chance of remaining in Spain?

Comment: With regard to the Brexit implications, it's unlikely, as long as you do whatever you need to do under the Spanish system to be legitimately "self employed" (something about which I know nothing, which is why I'm commenting rather than answering). The [directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) applies equally to those who "are workers or self-employed persons in the host Member State" (Art. 7(1)(a)) along with several other categories of people. Post-Brexit provisions will probably also treat such people equally.

Comment: Many Spanish cities have groups that help non-citizens in various ways at no charge. The one that helped me in Burgos was called Burgos Acoge.  There’s also a pretty good website called “Citizen’s Advice Bureau (CAB) Spain.”

Comment: Will you be working for other companies or only the Australian one? I don't know about Spanish employment law but in the UK you would be considered and employee and not a self-employed freelancer if you only had one client.

Comment: @MrAndySweet Probably just for this company - I won't be taking on multiple clients. Although this company is effectively an agency who contract out anywhere. I think I'll still be working for this one agency company though, not for their clients. Not sure though.

Comment: You would need to check with them first of all if you would be an employee, and if not then check with the Spanish tax authorities to see if having one client is possible when self-employed.